# Shutdown XML-RPC server from client/test-harness

Tags: java, android

My problem context is as below:-

1. I have an Apache XMLRPC server implemented on Java using Webserver
2. A client implemented in Android running on the device/emulator, connecting against the XML-RPC in step 1.
3. Test cases running on the Android emulator which pass data to the client, which in turn sends it to the server. The server does some comparisons etc. and sends response back to the client which then has logic to say if a test passed/failed.

All of this works fine however where I am stuck at the moment is, once I have run all my tests I would like to shutdown the server remotely i.e. through the test-case to Android client route. I can do something like "client.execute("server.shutDown"), which works fine, the only issue is since the server is shut-down it ends up hanging my client on the line "HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);"

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the shutdown procedure yourself? Then instead of shutting down immediately, schedule it a few seconds from now (Timer or Thread), reply to client HTTP 200 so it will get the response, and then -- shutdown.